# BeautifulSoup How to remove tags whose text has specific value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrape some articles from wikipedia, and have found that there are some entries I wish to exclude.

In the case below I want to exclude the two `a` tags whose content equals either `Archived` or `Wayback Machine`. It's not necessary to have the text as the factor. I see that the href value is also usable as an exclusions on the url `archive.org` or `/wiki/Wayback_Machine`

```
<li id="cite_note-22">
    <span class="mw-cite-backlink">
        <b>
            <a href="#cite_ref-22" aria-label="Jump up" title="Jump up">^</a>
        </b>
    </span> 
    <span class="reference-text">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://www.somelink.com">Article Text I want to keep</a> 
        <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://www.someotherlink.com">Archived</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Wayback_Machine" title="Wayback Machine">Wayback Machine</a>
    </span>
</li>
```

I've attempted to use decompose as below. But have found that this returns an error `'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'`

```
removeWayback = BeautifulSoup.find_all('a', {'title':'Wayback Machine'})
removeArchive = BeautifulSoup.find(text="Archive")
removeWayback.decompose()
removeArchive.decompose()

removeWayback = BeautifulSoup.find_all('a', {'title':'Wayback Machine'})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/bs4/element.py", line 1780, in find_all generator = self.descendants
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

I've also attempted to use `exclude` but I have similar issues.

Is there a better way to ignore these links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<li id="cite_note-22">
    <span class="mw-cite-backlink">
        <b>
            <a href="#cite_ref-22" aria-label="Jump up" title="Jump up">^</a>
        </b>
    </span> 
    <span class="reference-text">
        <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://www.somelink.com">Article Text I want to keep</a> 
        <a rel="nofollow" class="external text" href="https://www.someotherlink.com">Archived</a>
        <a href="/wiki/Wayback_Machine" title="Wayback Machine">Wayback Machine</a>
    </span>
</li>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == 'a' and not re.search(r'Wayback|Archived|\^', t.text)):
    print(f"{anchor.text} - {anchor.get('href')}")
```

Output:

```
Article Text I want to keep - https://www.somelink.com
```

EDIT to answer the comment:

You'd match by `class` and `text` by using `attrs=` of `.find_all()` and dropping the regex condition into the loop.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for anchor in soup.find_all("a", attrs={"class": "external text"}):
    if not re.search(r'Wayback|Archived', anchor.text):
        print(f"{anchor.text} - {anchor.get('href')}")
```

Output:

```
Article Text I want to keep - https://www.somelink.com
```

Comment: That worked nicely for removing anything with the matching text. How can I match on href? Would it be `and not re.search(r'archive.org\^', t.href)`?

Comment: You would use `and not re.search(r'archive\.org', t.get("href")` but you don't have any `href`s with `archive.org` so that will match everything in your `html` example.

Comment: This all worked, thank you. I'll mark it as fixed. As an aside how can I get the class. It doesn't appear to be the same as href with `t.get("class")`